# Excel: Create a reusable table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a two sheets: The first sheet defines months with various inventory numbers per month. ie. January - 1 foozles, 2 bardles, 5 bazzles. February - 2 foozles, 3 bardles, 3 bazzles.

On the second sheet, I have monthly summaries. Each summary is the same big table of calculations derived from those inventory numbers for a given month -- eg. for each foozle, we need 4 parts, 3 hours of labor, etc., and then we can sum up total labor and cost breakdowns for each product. I am currently copy-pasting this giant table 12 times and then modifying the input ranges from the first sheet manually.

Is there a way to define this data table just once, and then reference it for each month based on a range of inputs from the first sheet? ie. "Display MonthlySummaryTable with values: Sheet1!A1:A12", "Display MonthlySummaryTable with values: Sheet1!B1:B12"

Comment: This could be coded as an Excel Macro. You'll probably want to start by recording a macro of you copying and modifying the sheet, and then go through that code and look for ways to automate the updates unique to each month.

Comment: Or you could store this data in a database and create forms and tables and code that drives the forms and data manipulation.

Comment: Have you considered reporting with just ONE sheet instead of 12, and using pivot tables, slicers, filters, etc to set the desired month? Every time I hear about one sheet for each month, my "wasted time and effort" alarm bells go off.